# Avoid or control circular references in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I really am done with this, but at least I want to know what's going on. Here we go:

My project is an ASP.NET Core Web Application with Code First Entity Framework Core and an Angular frontend.

I want to control when to load referenced objects. They can be useful, but they can also create circular references with internal errors on the frontend. (JSON would be infinitely long.)

Models:

```
class Book {
   public virtual ICollection<Page> Pages { get; set; }
   ...simple properties
}

class Page {
   public virtual Book Book { get; set; }
   ...simple properties
}
```

In this example, every book from *books* will have an empty/null *Pages* list.

```
using (var context = new MoneyStatsContext())
{
   var books = context.Books.Where(rule => rule.State == 1).ToList();
}
```

In this example, the *Pages* lists are not null, and every *Page* will have it's *Book* property set. Thus creating a circular reference.

```
using (var context = new MoneyStatsContext())
{
   var books = context.Books.Where(rule => rule.State == 1).Include(x => x.Pages).ToList();
}
```

How do I avoid the circular reference? Do I really have no other (simpler) choice than creating a new model and manually specifying each property?

```
.Select(new Book() {
   ...setting each property by hand
}
```

**Not-working-solutions I've found:**

- Tried setting this false and true. Doesn't seem to change anything.

```
public MyContext()
{
   this.ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
}
```

- Tried specifying this in Startup.cs, but *options* doesn't have a SerializerSettings property.

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
   options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming you are using the latest and greatest ASP .NET Core 3.1 with `System.Text.Json`, to handle reference loops you will need to switch "back" to `Newtonsoft.Json` (though it worth mentioning that `System.Text.Json` should be faster. Also support for reference loops handling is [coming](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30820), as [@Eric J.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/141172/eric-j) wrote in comments):

```
services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(x => x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore)
```

As for EF creating reference loops - it is called `relationship fixup` and you can't do a lot about it (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38937317/2501279) answer). `AsNoTracking` can help a little bit (but not in case of `Include`).

My personal approach is to return DTO's from endpoints and not entities directly.

**UPD**

In .NET 5.0 [`ReferenceHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.referencehandler.preserve?view=net-5.0) is introduced, so next should do the trick:

```
services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve)
```

Comment: .NET Framework 5.0 will support circular references https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30820

Comment: @EricJ. yes, but it is not released yet =(

Comment: This didn't exactly work as described, but I could be at fault not providing enough information. `AddMvc()` returns an `IMvcBuilder` which doesn't have an `AddNewtonsoftJson` method. I had to add the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` nuget package and use `AddControllers` instead of `AddMvc`.
Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55666898/2563731