# Why does the entity framework not map the customer entity in my order?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, api, entity-framework, postman

I have an order entity, inside it contains several entities `Customer`, `Store` and others, but Entity Framework does not fill those entities. I thought the relationships were wrong but I can't find why the entity framework does not map the entities within orders.

`Orders` and `Customers` entities:

```
public partial class Orders
{
    public Orders()
    {
        OrderItems = new HashSet<OrderItems>();
    }

    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int? CustomerId { get; set; }
    public byte OrderStatus { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime RequiredDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ShippedDate { get; set; }
    public int StoreId { get; set; }
    public int StaffId { get; set; }

    public virtual Customers Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual Staffs Staff { get; set; }
    public virtual Stores Store { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderItems> OrderItems { get; set; }
}

public partial class Customers
{
    public Customers()
    {
        Orders = new HashSet<Orders>();
    }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Orders> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

Entity Framework code fragment:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Orders>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.OrderId)
                .HasName("PK__orders__46596229F9C56686");

            entity.ToTable("orders", "sales");

            entity.Property(e => e.OrderId).HasColumnName("order_id");

            entity.Property(e => e.CustomerId).HasColumnName("customer_id");

            entity.Property(e => e.OrderDate)
                .HasColumnName("order_date")
                .HasColumnType("date");

            entity.Property(e => e.OrderStatus).HasColumnName("order_status");

            entity.Property(e => e.RequiredDate)
                .HasColumnName("required_date")
                .HasColumnType("date");

            entity.Property(e => e.ShippedDate)
                .HasColumnName("shipped_date")
                .HasColumnType("date");

            entity.Property(e => e.StaffId).HasColumnName("staff_id");

            entity.Property(e => e.StoreId).HasColumnName("store_id");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Customer)
                .WithMany(p => p.Orders)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.CustomerId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                .HasConstraintName("FK__orders__customer__0F4872E8");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Staff)
                .WithMany(p => p.Orders)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.StaffId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK__orders__staff_id__1130BB5A");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Store)
                .WithMany(p => p.Orders)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.StoreId)
                .HasConstraintName("FK__orders__store_id__103C9721");
        });
```

Controller code:

[image]

Response in Postman:

[image]

Comment: Might want to put some Where clause in your controller .. dumping an entire db down the wire is a good start towards users DOSing you accidentally

Comment: I agree friend. I will put some limitations later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the options is to [eager load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager) them via `Include`:

```cs
return await _context.Orders
    .Include(o => o.Customer)
    .Include(o => o.Staff)
    .Include(o => o.Store)
    .ToListAsync()
```

For more info and options please check out the ["Loading Related Data" doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/).

Comment: It works when I debug the API, but when I make the request (POSTMAN - GET) I get a "500 Internal Server Error".
The VS2019 debugging console throws me the following "A possible object cycle was detected which is not supported. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32".

Comment: @Aetos2501 please check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62985944/2501279) answer