# Entity Framework Core 7 - composite key mapping problem

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

I am struggling to create the necessary attributes and code to allow me to retrieve all information from 3 tables I have.

The tables are:

`Recipe` table:

| Column | Type |
| --- | --- |
| RecipeId | int (Key) |
| Title | varchar |

`Ingredients` table:

| Column | Type |
| --- | --- |
| IngredientId | int (Key) |
| Description | varchar |

`Ingredients_Mapping` table:

| Column | Type |
| --- | --- |
| RecipeId | int (Key) |
| IngredientId | int (Key) |
| Quantity | int (Key) |

Hopefully the above makes sense. Each recipe may contain many ingredients. When I've pulled back details before it has been a simple one and I've added a `.Include(x => x.Whatever)` to extract the data from the joining table.

Here's the code:

```
public class Recipe
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public Ingredient[] Ingredients { get; set; }
}

public class Ingredient
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class IngredientMapping
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int RecipeId { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int IngredientId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}

public async Task<List<Recipe>> GetAllRecipesAsync()
{
    return await _MyDbContext.Recipes
                             .Include(x => x.???)
                             .OrderBy(b => b.Title).ToListAsync();
}
```

Could somebody please advise how I can do this please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two main ways to configure the [many-to-many relationship](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many) in EF Core - either by setting two entities up and having EF Core to generate the join table without explicitly exposing it:

```cs
public class Recipe
{
    // ...
    public List<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
}

public class Ingredient
{
    // ...
    public List<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }
}
```

Or setting up the join table explicitly, which should be the case taking in account the need to store the additional information in it (`Quantity`):

```cs
public class Recipe
{
    // ...
    public List<RecipeIngredient> RecipeIngredient { get; set; }
}

public class Ingredient
{
    // ...
    public List<RecipeIngredient> RecipeIngredients { get; set; }
}

// for 7th version, otherwise use 
// modelBuilder.Entity<RecipeIngredient>().HasKey(e => new {e.RecipeId,e.IngredientId }) 
[PrimaryKey(nameof(RecipeId), nameof(IngredientId))] 
public class RecipeIngredient
{
    public int RecipeId { get; set; }
    public Recipe Recipe { get; set; }

    public int IngredientId { get; set; }
    public Ingredient Ingredient { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

This should already be fully defined relationship but if needed you can apply the configuration via [model builder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#join-entity-type-configuration) (also see [options to set up composite key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations)).

Comment: Gourou Stron With two primary keys it's not a problem?

Comment: You just need to declare the compound key in your fluent config instead of using `[Key]` attributes, eg `modelBuilder.Entity<RecipeIngredient>().HasKey(e => new {e.RecipeId,e.IngredientId });`.  And you can have Many-to-many _and_ a linking entity if you want.  There's an example in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many

Comment: @Laaziv updated code to correctly support composite key

Comment: Thank you for the reply but this hasn't worked for me. I have made the changes to the classes as per your code. What should I then enter for the Service call? I have:

await _recipesDbContext.Recipes.Include(c => c.IngredientMappings).OrderBy(b => b.Title).ToListAsync();

But this creates the following error below.

System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32. Consider using ReferenceHandler.Preserve on JsonSerializerOptions to support cycles.

Comment: @Dan actually it has. Now you have completely another problem - check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62985944/2501279) answer.

Comment: @GuruStron Ah thanks, that fixed it but another problem appears. My ingredient and recipe objects are returned as null. It must be missing some type of mapping?

"recipeIngredients": [
{
   "recipeId": 4,
   "recipe": null,
   "ingredientId: 2,
   "ingredient": null,
   "quantity": 8
}
]

Comment: This is my service code:
_recipesDbContext.Recipes.Include(c => c.Category).Include(x => x.RecipeIngredients).OrderBy(b => b.Title).ToListAsync();

Comment: @Dan it is hard to tell without full repro, I would argue that it is worth of separate question, but be sure to provide full [mre].

Answer (score 1):

[Guru Stron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75639314/10871073) is fine but, if you have problem with two primary keys, use this config:

```
public class Recipe
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public required string Title { get; set; }
        public virtual List<IngredientMapping> IngredientMappings { get; set; }
    }

    public class Ingredient
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public required string Title { get; set; }
        public List<IngredientMapping> ingredientMappings { get; set; }
    }

    public class IngredientMapping
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int RecipeId { get; set; }        
        [Required]
        public int IngredientId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public virtual required Recipe Recipe { get; set; }
        public virtual required Ingredient Ingredient { get; set; }        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for not responding earlier, I've had family things to take care of. I got this working with a mixture of the above answers and some reading up and trial and error. Hopefully this will help somebody else who was in my position, here is my finished code:

```
public class Ingredient
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

[PrimaryKey(nameof(RecipeId), nameof(IngredientId))]
public class RecipeIngredient
{
    public int RecipeId { get; set; }
    public int IngredientId { get; set; }
    public Ingredient Ingredient { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}

public class Recipe
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Title { get; set; }   
    public List<RecipeIngredient> RecipeIngredients { get; set; }
}
```