# EF Core: Many to many relationship as nested list without circular references

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

This is a problem that I couldnt solve and I hope one of you can help me.

Basically I have a simple database where 2 entities have a many-to-many relationship. For example:

There are users and roles. One user can have multiple roles, and one role can be added to multiple users. So there is a table called "UserRolesMapping".

Now I built a .net core 6 web api with EF core to query all users with their mapped roles. My DTO should look something like id, name, List.

I scaffolded my db context from my database and the many-to-many relationship got split into 2 one-to-many relationships with the mapping table. (This makes sense).

BUT: If I query all users and include the mapping entries, there is a circular reference because a user has a list of mapping entries and a role also, so if I include Role in the mapping entries there is an object cycle.

How can I resolve that? One way is to use .Select from LINQ but this solution is not ideal for me. Do you guys have any solutions for my problem?

If the scenario is hard to understand, I can also provide sample code, just let me know in the comments.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you share the related code about the table/class definition and the query statement, and share the detailed error message about the "circular reference"?  It is better to create a minimal, complete sample to reproduce the problem, then we can directly test it. Besides, you can try to avoid the circular reference by setting the Serializer Options, refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62985907/), code like this: "services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(x => x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore)"