# Handle circular reference with entity framework or automapper

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, automapper, .net-7.0

Im trying to learn and understand how to use entity framework and automapper with relations.
And maby more specifically circular references.

Lets say i have 3 objects:

```
public class Author
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Book>? Books { get; set; }
}
public class Book
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Author Author { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Page>? Pages { get; set; }
}
public class Page
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public Book Book { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; }
}
```

When fetching author i would want my response to be something like this:

```
{
    "id": "author1",
    "firstName": "famous",
    "lastName": "author",
    "books": [
        {
            "id": "book1",
            "name": "famousBookName",
            "pages": [
                {
                    "id": "page1",
                    "text": "..."
                },
                {
                    "id": "page2",
                    "text": "..."
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But when fetching a book i'd want the response like:

```
{
    "id": "book1",
    "name": "famousBookName",
    "author": {
        "id": "author1",
        "firstName": "famous",
        "lastName": "author"
    },
    "pages": [
        {
            "id": "page1",
            "text": "..."
        },
        {
            "id": "page2",
            "text": "..."
        }
    ]
}
```

And when fetching a page i would want the response like:

```
{
    "id": "page1",
    "text": "...",
    "book": {
        "id": "book1",
        "name": "famousBookName"
    },
    "author": {
        "id": "author1",
        "firstName": "famous",
        "lastName": "author"
    }
}
```

however, what i end up with is something like this:

```
{
    "id": "author1",
    "firstName": "famous",
    "lastName": "author",
    "books": [
        {
            "id": "book1",
            "name": "famousBookName",
            "pages": [
                {
                    "id": "page1",
                    "text": "...",
                    "book": {
                        "id": "book1",
                        "name": "famousBookName",
                        "author": {
                            "id": "author1",
                            "firstName": "famous",
                            "lastName": "author",
                            "books": [...]
                        },
                        "pages": [...]
                    },
                    "author": {
                        "id": "author1",
                        "firstName": "famous",
                        "lastName": "author",
                        "books": [...]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to solve this? either telling entityframework to skip populating the circular references, or through automapper settings?

Or is the only way to add multiple DTO's that i map to?
one for author with books, one for author without books
one for book without author and pages, one for book with author and pages
one for page without book and author, and one for book with page and author

I feel like doing that will end up with an absolut huge amout of classes as the project grows

A solution could be to use .select() and simply map the objects manualy possibly even into anonumys types. But is this good practise?

Comment: This would be the behavior I would expect. If you do not want to include circular references, remove the Pages.Book-property. You might also consider separating your EF-entities from types used in a webserver or other types of export, Also, is your `Book.Book` a typo? It is not included in your expected outputs.

Comment: Sorry yes, the Book.Book is a typo, it should be a reference to the author.

The classes here are to explain the issue without all the extra overhead of my actuall classes.
The problem is that the consumer want information about the related book and author when they fetch a specific page.

I am mapping it into DTO's, but that keeps the references.

Comment: If you query for a book, and include the author, that author.books should always include the book you queried for. But depending on how you write your query it may or may not include *all* books by the author. I'm not sure how you are doing your mapping, but the mapping should not *need* to include all references.

Comment: Why do you want to "solve" this?

Comment: For ASP.NET Core - check also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62985944/2501279)

Comment: @JonasH that is completly correct, the problem here is that when i query a book, i want to include the author, but i see no reason why that author.Books should be populated with the queried book, i'd preffere it to be null or atleast an empty array. as i dont need to return the book information twise to the consumer

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to configure the json serializer so it won't follow circular references.

You can do this by configuring the service for all the project adding the line in program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = System.Text.Json.Serialization.ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles;
});
```

You can also do it on per request basis adding the configuration to the json serializer on your request:

```
 var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerOptions
 {

         DefaultIgnoreCondition = System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnoreCondition.Never,
         MaxDepth = 1

 };

 var jsonContent = JsonSerializer.Serialize(author);
```

Then you can send the json content from the controller

Answer (score 0):

The awnser turned out to be rather simple by just adding:

```
.PreserveReferences()
```

To the automapper mapping profiles.