# EF Core : how to model a relationship attribute?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I currently have EF Core code, modeling the following ER:

[image]

I would like to add a relationship attribute, like the following:\

[image]

Here are the relevant parts of the current code:

```
public class System
{
    public string SystemId { get; set; }
    public List<Component> Components { get; set; } = new List<Component>();
}

public class Component
{
    public int ComponentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

----

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<System>()
            .HasMany(s => s.Components)
            .WithMany();
}
```

This code built a lookup table in the database, linking the two entities. Like this:

[Current tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaFvM.png)

For the change I'd like to achieve, I would expect a new column (i.e. version) in the lookup table, but I could not find any way to make it happen.

I have tried to change the code as following:

```
public class System
{
    public string SystemId { get; set; }
    public List<ComponentRelationship> Components { get; set; } = new List<ComponentRelationship>();
}

public class ComponentRelationship
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public Component Component { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
}
```

But it doesn't really do what I want.

What ways exist to create a relationship attribute?

Comment: Your diagram is showing one-to-many relationship while you actually have designed mmany-to-many, is that actually what is desired/need?

Comment: @GuruStron The desired outcome is an unidirectional many-to-many. I forgot a crow's foot. I edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Both your diagrams shows one-to-many relationship while in your entity code you have declared [unidirectional many-to-many](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many#unidirectional-many-to-many) relationship.</s>

Since many-to-many is actually what you need (i.e. system can have many components and component can belong to many systems) than you can simply add [payload to the join table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many#many-to-many-and-join-table-with-payload). The easiest option would be to declare explicit join entity:

```
public class SystemComponentVersion
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public System System{ get; set; }
    public Component Component { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
}

public class System
{
    public string SystemId { get; set; }
    public List<Component> Components { get; set; } = new List<Component>();
    public List<SystemComponentVersion> SystemComponents{ get; set; } = new List<SystemComponentVersion>();
}

public class Component
{
    public int ComponentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public List<System> Systems { get; set; } = new List<System>();
    public List<SystemComponentVersion> SystemComponents{ get; set; } = new List<SystemComponentVersion>();
}
```

With something along the following with fluent API:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<System>()
        .HasMany(e => e.Components)
        .WithMany(e => e.Systems)
        .UsingEntity<SystemComponentVersion>());
}
```

Comment: Worked great, thank you! I just had to change `public System System{ get; set; }` (in class `SystemComponentVersion`) to `public string SystemId`. Otherwise I would get `A possible object cycle was detected` when loading the System. 
Also, I removed the reference to system in the component class as I only need a unidirectional relationship and I never need to navigate from component to system. (I'm not 100% sure of this last statement. Is it actually correct? So far it's working...)

Comment: @spike093 this is due to the fact that you share EF Core entities with your models for serialization. Depending on the case you can keep using unidirectional relationships or switch to DTOs. Checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62985944/2501279) for some details.