# Circular references from API controller call

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, relationship

I have an app I'm building that has the following entities.

```cs
namespace MusicManager.Shared.Entities
{
    public class Piece
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public Publisher? Publisher { get; set; }
        public int? PublisherId { get; set; }
        public List<Part>? Parts { get; set; } = new List<Part>();
    }
}

namespace MusicManager.Shared.Entities
{
    public class Publisher
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public List<Piece>? Pieces { get; set; } = new List<Piece>();
    }
}
```

I have the following methods withing my contollers.

```cs
public async Task<ServiceResponse<List<Piece>>> GetAllPieces(bool order)
{
    var response = new ServiceResponse<List<Piece>>
    {
        Data = (order) ?
        await _dataContext.Pieces
            .OrderBy(x => x.Title)
            .Include(x => x.Publisher)
            .ToListAsync() :
        await _dataContext.Pieces
            .Include(x => x.Publisher)
            .ToListAsync()
    };

    return response;
}

public async Task<ServiceResponse<List<Publisher>>> GetAllPublishers(bool order)
{
    var response = new ServiceResponse<List<Publisher>>
    {
        Data = (order) ?
        await _dataContext.Publishers
            .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
            .Include(x => x.Pieces)
            .ToListAsync() :
        await _dataContext.Publishers
            .Include(x => x.Pieces)
            .ToListAsync()
    };

    return response;
}
```

Running the Get call for all Pieces gives me a circular result, the call goes to get the publisher, the publisher reference references pieces, and back and forth.  I think I need to utilize DTOs to restrict the return, but I'm kind of lost as to how I should go about doing it.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: How do you configure the relations? This looks like it ought to work on conventions alone but apparently EF doesn't see the 1-to-many the right way.

Comment: What version of .Net are you using?

Comment: I'm using .net 7.  I configure the relations through the models and user dotnet ef migrations to build it out.

Comment: This is why people use "view types", to hide the implementation details of your data model, and to define a contract you can support in future versions.

Answer (score 0):

> I think I need to utilize DTOs to restrict the return, but I'm kind of lost as to how I should go about doing it.

Yes, this is quite common approach to handle such problems. For example you can introduce several DTOs and map to them manually:

```
public class PieceDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public PublisherInfoDto Publisher { get; set; }
}

public class PublisherInfoDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    // no "reverse" property 
}
```

And query looking like this:

```
await _dataContext.Pieces
    .Select(p => new PieceDto
     {
         Id = p.Id, 
         // rest of "simple" props
         Publisher = new PublisherInfoDto
         {
            Id = p.Publisher.Id // ...
         }
     })
    .ToListAsync();
```

And similar with `PublisherDto` + `PieceInfoDto`.

Notes:

- You can use library like [AutoMapper](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/) with it's [Queryable Extensions](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html) to reduce some typing for mappings
- Manually mapping to the same classes in the final projection should also work since EF will not track such projections and will not perform relationship fixup. I.e. something like:

  ```cs
  await _dataContext.Pieces
      .Select(p => new Piece
      {
          Id = p.Id, 
          // rest of "simple" props
          Publisher = new Publisher
          {
              Id = p.Publisher.Id,
              Name = p.Publisher.Name 
              // do not fill the reference property
          }
      })
      .ToListAsync();
  ```
- Also check out [Avoid or control circular references in Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62985907/2501279)